# Запуск с заданной конфигурацией регионов

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

Требуется при запуске screen разделить окно терминала на три региона и в каждом запустить какое либо терминальное приложение.
Хочется это делать скриптом/конфигурацией, а не горячими клавишами.
Возможно ли это?

Уточню: речь идёт про регионы, создаваемые `Ctra + a |` и `Ctrl + a S`

UPD: читая man, научился делить окно на регионы, запускать приложения пока нет.
В домашнем каталоге создаём файл `.screenrc`

```
split -v
split
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ответ с параллельного сайта](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207089/110559):

используйте `~/.screenrc` на той машине, где запускаете программу *screen*.

пример:

```
split
screen -t top top
focus
screen -t shell
```

где:

- `split` — разделить текущее окно/регион горизонтально
- `focus` — переключиться на следующий регион
- `screen -t name [command]` — задать имя для текущего окна/региона и выполнить команду.